# Java polymorphism: How to indicate comparison should be made using subclass?

Tags: java, oop, object, polymorphism

Introductory question incoming! The following code...

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Object> A = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Integer I = new Integer(3);
    Double D = new Double(3.14);

    A.add(I);
    A.add(D);

    if (A.get(0) > 2)
    {
        System.out.print("Hello World");      
    }  
  }
}
```

... fails to compile

```
bad operand types for binary operator '>'
        if (A.get(0) > 2)
                     ^
  first type:  Object
  second type: int
```

How can I indicate that I want the comparison to be made with the subclass `Integer` rather than with `Object`?

Comment: Cast it to `Integer`?

Comment: Since you declared the `ArrayList` to hold type `Object`, and the `>` operator does not apply to `Object`, this is normal. Generics are assertions for the compiler about type. If you don't assert a type that supports the operations you intend, then those operations will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both `Integer` and `Double` extend `Number` then redefine you ArrayList as

```
ArrayList<Number> A = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

then

```
if (A.get(0).intValue () > 2)
```

Comment: `A.get(0).doubleValue ()` is better.